# How to create 51-android.rules file

Tags: ubuntu, usb

This command line

$ gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

doesn't work for my ubuntu 12.4.

When I execute it, gedit is suppose to pop up, but nothing happens

Comment: Invoke `sudoedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` in terminal

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some problem with gedit, did you have any error message from console ?

Try nano or vim ;) Console program never fails :)

sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Answer (score 1):

> You need to add a udev file in your `/etc/udev/rules.d/` folder named as `51-android.rules.`
> [..]

To create file `51-android.rules`, just type following commands in your terminal.

```sh
sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

https://twikkie.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/how-to-debug-android-application-on-device-via-ubuntu/

Comment: You should include the main parts of what is described on the page you sited directly to your post. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer